# i am making a qibla direction app and my direction for qible is coming slightly off target. My code is given below

Tags: compass, direction

Here is my code to find qibla direction on compass.
it works all fine
the compass is working
even the north, east, west, south is showing fine but the direction of qibla is not accurate.
please if you can correct if something is missing or wrong in my code.

****   package com.example.compassone;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    ImageView kaba;

    private static SensorManager sensorservices;
    private Sensor sensor;
    private float CurrentDegree = 0f;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        kaba = findViewById (R.id.kaba);
        sensorservices = (SensorManager) getSystemService (SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorservices.getDefaultSensor (Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume ();
        if (sensor != null){
            sensorservices.registerListener (this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText (this, "Not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause ();
        sensorservices.unregisterListener (this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      int degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);
        RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation (CurrentDegree, -degree, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        ra.setDuration (1000);
        ra.setFillAfter (true);
        kaba.startAnimation(ra);
        CurrentDegree = -degree;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
} ********
```